# Django - Get POST data from other URL

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to integrate a payment gateway in my platform using Django. It's called "mercadopago" and when a client pays sends my a couple of parameters but I don't know how can I get them. Here you have the full request:

```
WSGIRequest
path:/mercadopago/response/,
GET:<QueryDict: {u'topic': [u'payment'], u'id': [u'815566889']}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {}>,
COOKIES:{},
META:{'CONTENT_LENGTH': '97',
 'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
 u'CSRF_COOKIE': u'rUp9eLvT9cCMedg1INM5dlvEjPJ9ZRtg',
 'DOCUMENT_ROOT': '/var/www',
 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1',
 'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL': 'max-age=259200',
 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'keep-alive',
 'HTTP_HOST': 'micuento.com',
 'HTTP_VIA': '1.1 e-00004446 (squid/3.4.3)',
```

How can I access this items  **{u'topic': [u'payment'], u'id': [u'815566889']}**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the data with request.GET.

```
id = request.GET['id']
topic = request.GET['topic']
```

Or you can try with request.GET.get()